# Is there a AD lockout script showing actual machine

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Does anyone know or have a script which tells you the actual device locking out an AD account. I have a working script which lists all users locked out in the last 3 days which tells me the DC its locked out. Rather than having to connect to this or via event log and locate the event id, i wanted to know if there was a PS script out there which would output where. Then we can go to said device and fix.

Google has brought up a few suggestions but not the clearest and some just do what i can already get via the current script.

Thanks

Comment: Well, unless you have your logs centralized, the script would still need to fetch the event logs from the locking DC

Comment: Ok thats fine. So my question woud be is there a script which can do this. Even refining to a username specific? Save a lot of time with helpdesk people having to pass to server support to get this info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This returns an array of PsObjects, where:

- property `TargetUserName` holds the user SamAccountName that is locked out
- property `TargetDomainName` contains the computer name where the lockout originated from
- property `EventDate` will show the time and date the lockout occurred

Code:

```
# get the domain controller that has the PDC Emulator Role
$pdc = (Get-ADDomain).PDCEmulator
$splat = @{
    FilterHashtable = @{LogName="Security";Id=4740}
    MaxEvents       = 100
    ComputerName    = $pdc
    Credential      = Get-Credential -Message "Please enter credentials for '$pdc'"
}

$lockedOut = Get-WinEvent @splat | ForEach-Object {
    # convert the event to XML and grab the Event node
    $eventXml = ([xml]$_.ToXml()).Event
    # create an ordered hashtable object to collect all data
    # add some information from the xml 'System' node first
    $evt = [ordered]@{
        EventDate = [DateTime]$eventXml.System.TimeCreated.SystemTime
        Level     = [System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventLevel]$eventXml.System.Level
    }
    # next see if there are childnodes under 'EventData'
    if ($eventXml.EventData.HasChildNodes) {
        $eventXml.EventData.ChildNodes | ForEach-Object { 
            $name = if ($_.HasAttribute("Name")) { $_.Name } else { $_.LocalName }
            $value = $_.'#text'

            if ($evt[$name]) { 
                # if an item with that name already exists, make it an array and append
                $evt[$name] = @($evt[$name]) + $value
            }
            else { $evt[$name] = $value }
        }
    }
    # output as PsCustomObject. This ensures the $result array can be written to CSV easily
    [PsCustomObject]$evt
}

# output on screen
$lockedOut | fl *

# output to csv file
$lockedOut | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\lockedout.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

If you want to search for a specific user (SamAccountName) for instance, just do

```
$lockedOut | Where-Object { $_.TargetUserName -eq 'UserSamAccountName' }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Why thank you. That seems great. I will give that a test.

Comment: These seems to work but fails to output anything. This is without a Specific user variable included.

Comment: @Kevlar To output, simply do `$lockedOut | fl *`

Comment: gotcha. Thank you. I will give that a go when back at my desk.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. That gives me much more than we were getting before. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @Kevlar Yes, it will list all properties found in the EventData node, but if that is too much, just filter out what you need like with `$lockedOut | Select-Object EventDate, TargetUserName, TargetDomainName`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you @Theo

Comment: I also presume it would be easily adaptable to use the '''$lockedOut | Where-Object { $_.TargetUserName -eq 'UserSamAccountName' }''' and input a custom entry so you input user1 for example and it would search.

Comment: @Kevlar Yes, just change `'SamAccountName'` to that of the specific user and you would get either $null if that user is not found in the list or the object for that single user.